# Are there any limitations on the use of ARCore Geospatial API?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

Can ARCore Geospatial API be used for free? According to the following link, it says that it's free, but are there any limitations or restrictions?
https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/Make-the-world-your-canvas-ARCore-Geospatial-API.html

I actually tried using it and couldn't confirm if there are any limitations such as the number of requests allowed.